# Indesign grep - last character/letter

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep, character

Im trying to apply a grep to my paragraph style. 
this is the text: "s. 02"
I want to apply some special formatting for the last character, "2".

But it seems i cant target it, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grepping for `.{1}$` should do the trick.

See http://regexr.com/3fsks for test

Comment: My pleasure, have a good day